# Oracle11g installation error for Listener

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When installing Oracle11.2.0 g, I get database Configuration Assistant warning- Enterprise manager configuration failed due to foll. error:Listener is not up or database service is not registered with it.Start the Listener and register database service and run EM Configuration assistant again.Please guide me how to proceed..
Hence I am not able to connect JavaJDBC program with Oracle

Answer (score 3):

First of all what is your Database Version and Operating System

Register your database with the listener

Add `SID_LIST_LISTENER` in your listener.ora file present in `$ORACLE_HOME\network\admin`

**Example**

```
LISTENER=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sale-server)(PORT=1521))
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc))))
SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
    (SID_DESC=
    (GLOBAL_DBNAME=sales.us.example.com)
      (ORACLE_HOME=/oracle11g)
      (SID_NAME=sales))
    (SID_DESC=
       (SID_NAME=plsextproc)
      (ORACLE_HOME=/oracle11g)
      (PROGRAM=extproc)))
```

**Refer to this link**

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/listener.htm

After Editing `listener.ora` restart the listener with the help of following command....

```
lsnrctl reload
```

Then try to start Enterprise Manager as follows

```
emctl start dbconsole
```

[Reference from the link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2317767)

[Reconfigure Oracle Enterprise Manager on windows](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/oracle-architecture-configuration/changing-windows-hostname-and-oracle-enterprise-manager/)

[ORACLE_UNAME](http://bidope.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/environment-variable-oracle_unqname-not-defined-please-set-oracle_unqname-to-da-tabase-unique-name/)

Comment: @ Gaurav Soni:  my DB version is Oracle11.2.0 g and OS is Windows7. I added the SID_LIST_LISTENER to listener.ora and restarted the listener.ora using lsnrctl reload on cmd which gave        Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))                                               The command completed successfully  ...But is my Database registered with the listener now.?..                                                              Environment variable ORACLE_UNQNAME not defined.set it to database unique name.how to proceed

Comment: when I try starting Enterprise Manager using emctl start dbconsole on cmd  I get error environment variable ORACLE_UNQNAME not defined.set it to database unique name????

Comment: @DM111:you need to set your enviornment variable ,i have added a link of how to add enviornment vairable

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the database Listener is running. You can check by typing 'servies.msc' in your Start>Run box and see if the database listener is running.

Comment: How to do it...How to register the DB with the listener

Comment: See below for your answer from Gaurav Soni